# Problems with Collection sort

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I use code below.

where Sorting.costItemBySortKey is static Comparator

**repository.addCostItems(items)** save items to SQLite database.

I found that on some devices not all items saved to db.

What is wrong? I thing it happens becouse i use Collections.sort before saving, isn't it?

```
protected void createCostItems(){
        List<CostItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] itemsName  = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_cost_items);
        int[]    itemsIcon  = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.default_cost_item_icons);
        int[]    itemsGroup = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.default_cost_item_group);
        int[]    costType   = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.default_cost_item_cost_type);
        int[]    costSort   = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.default_cost_item_sort1);
        CostItem item;
        for (int i=0; i< itemsName.length; i++) {
            item = new CostItem(i, itemsName[i], itemsIcon[i], itemsGroup[i], costType[i], costSort[i]);
            items.add(item);
        }        
        Collections.sort(items, Sorting.costItemBySortKey);
        repository.addCostItems(items);
        costItems=null;
    }
```

Code for saving to db

```
public void addCostItem(CostItem costItem){
            costItemDataAdapter.appendItem(database, costItem);
        }

public void appendItem(SQLiteDatabase db, T item){
        DataRow row = this.itemToRow(item);
        if(item.getId() == Item.NEW_ID)
            row.column("_id").setValue(null);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        List<DataColumn> rowColumns = row.Columns();

        for (DataColumn column: rowColumns){
            if(column.getDataType().equals("integer"))
                values.put(column.getName(), column.getInteger());
            if(column.getDataType().equals("varchar"))
                values.put(column.getName(), column.getString());
            if(column.getDataType().equals("real"))
                values.put(column.getName(), column.getFloat());         
        }

        int id = (int)db.insert(this.Name, null, values);
        item.setId(id);
    }
```

Comment: comparator only sorts the items. it will not delete any. the problem is something else. Maybe some constraints getting violated, etc...

Comment: post the code which stores this in your db

Comment: No buddy, the code which actually inserts in the db, -> code inside addCostItem()

Comment: added code to answer

Comment: When i removed Collections.sort all items were saved. It happens on some devices, for example HTC Desire 820G :-(